# How do I install metapost.sty on Ubuntu?

Tags: installing, emacs, ubuntu

I have `\usepackage{metapost}` in my LaTeX file.  When I compile the file via Emacs I get this error:

`` ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `metapost.sty' not found. ``

On the terminal I then do `sudo tlmgr install metapost` which yields:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.aut.ac.nz/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package already present: metapost
```

I do `locate metapost.sty` and nothing is returned.

I also did `kpsewhich metapost` and nothing is returned.  (I don't know much about kpsewhich but I was looking at this post to figure out my problem: [Why does kpsewhich fail to find this file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306946/why-does-kpsewhich-fail-to-find-this-file))

This is what my $PATH looks like after running `'echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux
/snap/bin
```

Other Notes:

- I have accidentally installed `texlive-full` via `apt-get` but that posed some problems so I performed a `purge` and `autoremove` and instead did a manual install via the instructions here https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
- With my current setup I am able to compile documents but adding packages is problematic.

Comment: There is no `metapost.sty` that I know of. Where did you find mention of `\usepackage{metapost}`?

Comment: @egreg I was trying to produce a [kanji-sheet](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/kanji-sheet.pdf) by reverse engineering the [source code](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/kanji-sheet.tex) found on [TUG tex showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/).  The source code was using "MPgraphics" and so I thought I'd read up on package "mpgraphics".  On CTAN the mpgraphics pacakge documentation mentions METAPOST so I assumed this was another package to install. If METAPOST is not a package that can be installed that will be the problem.  Doh!

Comment: The file you linked to uses ConTeXt, not LaTeX. It has built-in support for Metapost.